# I2C Communication between two Raspberry pi 4 boards

Tags: i2c, serial-communication

How to configure unreserved GPIO pins of raspberry pi 4 for I2C communication between two raspberry pi 4 boards, such that one raspberry pi 4 board act as master and another pi 4 board act as slave.

As Raspberry pi boards can be only masters and not slave, I tried to add a multiplexer bridge but didn't work well.

Comment: If you can't use the hardware i2c. Then you could bit bang an i2c instead. Try googling for "raspberry pi bit bang i2c slave".

Comment: Is I2C a must? I would recommend to use SPI as it’s much easier to handle.